# For each environment do we need separate GKE Cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, istio

I'm using a GKE. For single zone it is free of charge(only instance cost). For DEV we are using it but for another environment like QA/DEV/Production do we need separate GKE Cluster or inside the current GKE a different namespace will work ? which is the best way in cost and security

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your requirements. Both options are viable.

> environment like QA/DEV/Production do we need separate GKE Cluster

In a professional environment for a large enterprise, this would be different clusters in different [VPC](https://cloud.google.com/vpc) (one [VPC](https://cloud.google.com/vpc) per environment) and you might use separate projects as well, but not needed.

> inside the current GKE a different namespace will work

this is cheaper, but you have less separation. Only you know what you need.

Comment: Ok, let me take in this way. I am going via deploying DEV and QA in the same GKE cluster. My GKE is using istio ingress gateway. In that case what would be the ingree gateway Host IP. As ingress for istio seems to be unique like it comes from -n istio-system ?

Comment: Since for DEV and QA seprate load balancer address is needed in this Istio case it will be only 1 rght for both dev and QA ?

Comment: You should get the ip address from the load balancer that you use for exposing the gateway, but in most cases you want to create a specific static IP address. It is also recommended to create your environments as simple as possible, this makes it much easier to manage, so I would not recommend to combine DEV and QA.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can have a different namespaces within the same cluster for different environments. This would be cost effective.

*If you are using **nodeports** you need to take care of the below points :*

But nodeports have to be unique across same cluster. So if you're using nodeports to access your applications, you need different clusters(if you still want to have the same node ports across all environments. If not, you can use the same cluster with different namespaces.
Eg. if u have app1 with nodeport 30077 in Cluster1 namespace1 (used as dev)
you cannot have app1 deployed with nodeport 30077 in Cluster1 namespace2 (used as test)
but you can have app1 deployed with nodeport 3xxxx (except already used port - eg. in this case 30077) in cluster1 namespace2